# button add event click event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a button within a formview control on my page.

Because the button is contained within the formview, my code-behind can't see it.

So I did this:

```
Dim btnSave As Button = CType(fvCourse.FindControl("btnSave"), Button)
```

And then I added an event handler like this:

```
AddHandler btnSave.Click, AddressOf btnSave_Click

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.write("hey!")
End Sub
```

The problem is, I don't think it's working because I never see the "hey!" on my page.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Test it with a Msgbox or with a response.redirect()?
This way u can be 100% sure.

Comment: Where are you adding the event handler?

Comment: I am doing this all in page load - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about missing something, but I reckon you could do it a simpler way since you're using VB.  Give your button a command name and command argument first:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"
CommandArgument="1" CommandName="yes" />
```

These can be anything - typically you use the command name to determine which button a user clicked on, and the command argument to show the record id.

In your code-behind, attach a macro to the **ItemCommand** event of the FormView (which fires when something happens within it):

```
 Protected Sub FormView1_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewCommandEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemCommand

    Select Case e.CommandName.ToLower
        Case "yes"

            'test
            Label2.Text = "You chose " & e.CommandArgument.ToString

    End Select
End Sub Protected Sub FormView1_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewCommandEventArgs) Handles FormView1.ItemCommand

    Select Case e.CommandName.ToLower
        Case "yes"

            'test
            Label2.Text = "You chose " & e.CommandArgument.ToString

    End Select
End Sub
```

And in VB, that's all you need to do!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`ItemCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.itemcreated.aspx) event of the `FormView` for such things. If the `Button` is in the `ItemTemplate` you need to check for the `FormViewMode.ReadOnly`, for `EditItemTemplate` you need to use `Edit`:

```
Private Sub fvCourse_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles fvCourse.ItemCreated
    Select Case fvCourse.CurrentMode
        Case FormViewMode.Edit
            Dim btnSave As Button = DirectCast(fvCourse.FindControl("btnSave"), Button)
            AddHandler btnSave.Click, AddressOf btnSave_Click
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: The button is in ItemTemplate. Why should it be in the _ItemCreated event? - thanks

Comment: @999cm999: Because event handlers must be added on every postback and this event is triggered on every postback. It also ensures that it's called only in the correct FormViewMode and you don't get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: should I put all my controls in _ItemCreated?  Like all my asp:Labels, buttons, textboxes, etc? - thanks

Comment: I assume that you're mixing up something. If you handle `ItemCreated` and add the event-handler there, you're not creating your control(s) there. I've assumed that it's already added declaratively on aspx. So it's only a way to reference controls that are declared in a template. Hence i don't understand what you mean with _"put all controls there"_.